# What is Unloaded Type in Windbg?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I am trying to debug a memory dump and I am looking at one type as being labelled as

```
2c172a8c  1313427   1040234184 <Unloaded Type>
```

Does anyone know what this means exactly?

TIA

Andrew

Comment: Just to clarify I did check after I asked this, might have been better asking first :-S http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67357/where-should-i-ask-questions-related-to-windbg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means the type was defined by an assembly/dll that has been unloaded. Since it is no more present in memory, the debugger can not display more information about it.